# GTK+, Code::Blocks, не найден файл <gtk/gtk.h>

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks, gtk+

Ситуация такова, поставил себе **GTK+** по официальному мануалу, сделал в **Glade** интерфейс, написал программу, все проверил - работало.

Ушел делать дела, прихожу, все сломалось.

При попытке скомпилировать любой **GTK+** проект, даже новый, даже пустой, пишет:

```
fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory|
```

Я уже и **GTK+** переустановил, ВЕСЬ стек, и **Code::Blocks**, и руками везде пути прописал, и конфиги, но это не помогает.

Что это за черная магия, у кого-нибудь было такое?

Answer (score 0):

После нескольких часов, мне удалось выяснить, что проблема решается переключением в **Code::Blocks** стандартного компилятора на какой-нибудь другой. Потом можно вернуть назад. Компилятор для проекта как был **GTK+ MinGW 64**, так и остался.

Очень странная ерунда, видимо какой-то внутренний баг **Code::Blocks**

На всякий случай, вот настройки рабочей конфигурации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]